# Pandas style.apply matches between 2 dataframes with .isin

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and I want to check for their matches.

**Dataframe1**

```
some_stuff    big_number
a             111
b             112
c             117
```

**Dataframe2**

```
another_big_num
0111
0114
0117
```

If the number of df2 exists in df1, I want to highlight the entire row.
I understand that by using `.isin` I can check for the matches but I don't know how I can use `.style.applymap` provided by pandas in such a context.

So doing something like
`df_test1["big_number"].isin(df_test2["another_big_num"])` gives me the matches I want but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: @mozway that isn't the issue I am struggling with

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
def big_number(s,x):
    if s.big_number in x:
        return ['background-color: yellow'] * len(s)
    else:
        return ['background-color: white'] * len(s)

df_test1.style.apply(big_number(df_test1,df_test2["another_big_num"].values), axis=1)
```

Comment: Also, how can I save the result as a new excel file? Adding `.to_excel(...)` doesn't seem to work for me giving me `pandas.core.base.SpecificationError: Function names must be unique if there is no new column names assigned` this error.